# How to find relative x path of unique code?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, automation, appium

3 matching nodes.. all have same source code ..hence it is failing `//img[(@src='/PHYLINSPortlet/images/override-0.gif')]`

```
<img id="_PHYLINSPortlet_WAR_PHYLINSPortlet_INSTANCE_o3P5_:form_PolicyContent_UI2:Messages:0:j_id1885:0:j_id897" class="null" alt="" src="/PHYLINSPortlet/images/override-0.gif" style="border:0px"/>
```

This is the `xpath` of a dynamic button:

[image]

I need to click on all the buttons.

what I did is  --

```
    List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[(@src='/PHYLINSPortlet/images/override-0.gif')]"));
    for( WebElement button : buttons ) {
        button.click();
    }
```

Comment: How to find unique xpath

Comment: `id` attribute should be unique for each element. Check whether it is dynamic (changed each time after page refresh) or not

Comment: it is same for all the 3 buttons. i have attached image

Comment: On attached image you used `XPath` with `src` attribute to find element. Try `id`

Comment: id is dynamic for the button. every button has unique id

Comment: Share `HTML` that includes parent elements of target button

Comment: <a id="_PHYLINSPortlet_WAR_PHYLINSPortlet_INSTANCE_o3P5_:form_PolicyContent_UI2:Messages:0:j_id1885:0:j_id896" class="iceCmdLnk" href="javascript:;" onblur="setFocus('');" onclick="var form=formOf(this);form['_PHYLINSPortlet_WAR_PHYLINSPortlet_INSTANCE_o3P5_:form_PolicyContent_UI2:_idcl'].value='_PHYLINSPortlet_WAR_PHYLINSPortlet_INSTANCE_o3P5_:form_PolicyContent_UI2:Messages:0:j_id1885:0:j_id896';return iceSubmitPartial(form,this,event);" onfocus="setFocus(this.id);" title="To Override" style="">

Comment: <img id="_PHYLINSPortlet_WAR_PHYLINSPortlet_INSTANCE_o3P5_:form_PolicyContent_UI2:Messages:0:j_id1885:0:j_id897" class="null" alt="" src="/PHYLINSPortlet/images/override-0.gif" style="border:0px"/>
</a>

Answer (score 0):

It is little bit difficult to provide the proper solution of your problem as you haven't shared your HTML.

As I observe the image in the question. You have 3 same types of image and want to click on any specific image lets say SECOND image then you need to use `xpath` methods like `following-sibling` or `preceding-sibling` to make your `xpath` unique

Example :-

Suppose you have any unique column in your table (Rule id) or you want to click a specific image.e.g. rule id `Val01014` image

Use the methods like following `xpath` -

```
//img[@src='/PHYLINSPortlet/images/override-0.gif']/preceding-sibling::td[text()='Val_01014']
```

OR

```
//img[@src='/PHYLINSPortlet/images/override-0.gif']/following-sibling::td[text()='Val_01014']
```